# how to hide tab bar only in home screen?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo

i want to hide tab bar in 1st screen only and show in other screens, how can i achieve this. any help is appreciated

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Home',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="ios-home" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },
Quotes: {
screen: QuoteScreen,
navigationOptions: {
  tabBarLabel: 'Quotes',
  tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
  <Icon name="ios-quote" color={tintColor} size={24} />
  )
}
  },
   About: {
    screen: AboutScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'About',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="ios-person" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
 },
  Books: {
    screen: BoookScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Books',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="ios-book" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  },
  Videos: {
    screen: VideoScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      tabBarLabel: 'Videos',
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
      <Icon name="ios-videocam" color={tintColor} size={24} />
      )
    }
  }

},
{
  tabBarOptions: {

    activeTintColor: 'yellow',
    inactiveTintColr: 'white',
    activeBackgroundColor:'black',
    inactiveBackgroundColor:'black'


  }
});

export default createAppContainer(TabNavigator);
```

show tab bar only in home screen i tried hiding in tab bar option but it either hides the tab bar on all screens or tab bar is visible in all screens.what should i try to achieve the desired result? any help is appreciated. thanks in advance...

Comment: If you do not have the tabs on the home screen, how do you navigate to to the other screens?

Comment: @dentemm the home screen can contain buttons to programmatically navigate

Comment: i have 4 buttons  for navigating from homeview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `tabBarVisible: false,` to the home screen navigationOptions

Comment: it worked but instead of filling the area with background image its showing a white background in the place of tab bar